# Tikz-cd: Adjust white space around "description" style arrow label

Tags: tikz-cd

I am using the description style arrow label in Tikz-cd so that the label appears on top of the arrow with some white space around the label. The issue is, with small arrows and large labels, the white space eats up the entire arrow.

Thus I would like to shrink the white space around the label. In the Tikz-cd  documentation it says this can be accomplished with "inner sep," though I am not sure exactly how this is done.

Here is a minimal working example where I try to (unsuccessfully) modify the white space around the arrow label using inner sep.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    $$
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r, "f" description] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
    $$
    $$
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r, "f" description, inner sep = -2em] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
    $$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `inner sep` in the option `labels` of TikZ-CD.
You can also set it locally, for one or some labels only, with:

```
"<labeltext>" {description, inner sep = <dimension>}
```

See the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r, "f" description] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[labels={inner sep = .5pt}]
        A \ar[r, "f" description] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    In the following CD, the first label has a  standard inner sep, the second has an inner sep of .5pt: 
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r, "f" description] & B\\
        A \ar[r, "f" {description, inner sep = .5pt}] & B\\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: don't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX, use `\[...\]`, see here: [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I need. I also like how I can add your solution: "labels={inner sep = .5pt}" locally to the optional arguments of a single bad arrow. Thanks also for the tip on avoiding $$ ... $$, I have been using LaTeX for a while now and I still have so much to learn! :)

Comment: @user38770 Of course, you can, also without explicitly set `labels`. See my renewed answer.

Comment: @user38770 It might be better to use the `description` key (`description/.append style={inner sep = .5pt}`) instead of changing the `inner sep` for all `labels`. However, if all your labels should lie on top of the line, you can also do `labels = description` and don't have do specify `description` each time.

Answer (score 3):

Same result with `xy` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}

\begin{document}
    \[\xymatrix{
    A \ar[r]|f & B
    } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]